# Wrong focus when CMD+Tab with multiscreen

Tags: macos, display, spaces, mission-control, application-switcher

If I have:

- 2 Screens
- Setting "Displays have separate spaces" ON
- A Terminal window in each screen (Terminal is just an example, this happens with all apps)

Being focused on the Terminal window of my secondary screen I do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to another app and then back to Terminal, the focus goes to the primary screen rather than the one was focused before switching, this happens no matter which app I use, always the same.

Anyone knows what's the solution for this?

Comment: What version of Mac OS? And my experience has been it's based on which screen the curser is on.

Comment: Hey, is Yosemite. I've checked that as well, but it doesn't work for me, if the cursor is in the second screen, when switching apps the focus still goes to the primary one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a solution besides turning off "Displays have separate spaces".

For more detail - I think if you start on one display and alt-tab to a different program, it'll focus on a window for that program *on that same display* if one exists; it'll focus on a window on a different display only if one doesn't exist on the starting display.